# how to convert an array into single column in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, database, clickhouse

since i cant use conditions with ARRAY JOIN, i have to JOIN two tables and i can't find how to convert a simple array to a column.

```
WITH
    ['filter', 'words'] as filter_words
...
```

i tried this but id didn't work

```
WITH
    filter_words as (
        select arrayJoin(['%filter%', '%words%']) as filter_word
    )
```

Comment: could you describe the `input` (origin) and `output` (expected) data?

Comment: input is array like ['filter', 'words'], output is

column

'filter'

'words'

how to do line break here?

Comment: could you extend your question instead of using the comment area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this to convert a simple array to a column:

```
clickhouse-cloud :) WITH
    ['filter', 'words'] as filter_words
SELECT arrayJoin(filter_words) as col from system.one



WITH ['filter', 'words'] AS filter_words
SELECT arrayJoin(filter_words) AS col
FROM system.one

Query id: c86602c8-682d-469d-b2fe-75647321bf63

┌─col────┐
│ filter │
│ words  │
└────────┘
```